# Running multiple listening scripts on different ports in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project to make a chat app between mobile and java clients with my laravel website acting as a mediator for communication between them. I am new to laravel, so maybe some of the terms may not be correct.

So basically the problem is to run a websocket server on one port and simultaneously run a xmpp server to communicate with fcm/android on another port.
Individually they both are working fine on commands set by me.
But I am not able to run them simultaneously.
How should I go about it.
Secondly I don't know if it is fine to run two endless scripts on a simple website server.

Answer (score 0):

I running websocket with Laravel too.
And I use [Swoole](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src) to drive it.
https://github.com/swooletw/laravel-swoole

Comment: But does it allow concurrent scripts running?